# Missing binaries during git hook

Tags: linux, bash, git, environment-variables

Let's setup a *post-receive* hook for `git` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/path/to/www --git-dir=/path/to/git/test_CI.git checkout -f

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin #(<- this export does not help much)
yarn build
```

The first line work well, but `yarn build` fails, because the hook doesn't know *yarn* at all.
(Running `yarn` in my host-terminal works perfeclty, though. The host is running on Ubuntu 18.04. by the way.)

`which yarn` tells me the exact location of yarn:

> /home/.../.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/yarn

I can use this for the hook. **But** the path contains the current yarn versionnumber, which will cause other problems, once the systems gets updated.

Plus, nvm, or node or nuxt and so on won't be found next. So this is not a clever workaround.

How can you make *all* the things that you have access to in your teminal (not only `yarn`) available for the hook?

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin #(<- this export does not help much)
```

This adds `/usr/bin`, which should already be part of $PATH to begin with, so... it does not do much.

I would check, as seen in [`nvm-sh/nvm` issue 355](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/355) if you can have `~/.nvm/current/` symlink (symbolic link), in order for the `$PATH` to remain constant, even when npm is updated.